# Why does CMake repeat link libraries across link flags?

Tags: cmake, linker

I'm using a third party project that provides dependencies to link against via a pkg-config file, which I pass to my target via `target_link_libraries`. The final result looks something like this example:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(main)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(
  main
  PRIVATE -lfoo
          -Wl,--whole-archive
          -lbar
          -Wl,--no-whole-archive
          -lfoo
          -Wl,-Bdynamic
          -lbaz)
```

Where main.c is a trivial C source file:

```
$ cat main.c
int main() { return 0; }
```

When I run CMake's configure step and inspect the generated compile commands, I see some libraries duplicated across link flags:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build -GNinja
$ ninja -C build -t commands
/usr/bin/cc    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -c /home/ja/toy/main.c
: && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -o main  -lfoo  -Wl,--whole-archive  -lbar  -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lfoo  -Wl,-Bdynamic  -lbaz  -lbar  -lbaz && :
```

Clearly, `-lbar` was repeated across `--no-whole-archive` and `-Bdynamic`. Is this equivalent to the original `target_link_libraries` call? Why does CMake do this?

Additionally, I tried experimenting without the link flags, and noticed that CMake transforms `-lfoo -lbar -lfoo -lbaz` into `-lfoo -lbar -lfoo -lbaz -lbar -lbaz`. I suspect it might have something to do with the behavior described at [LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) but I do not understand the rationale behind doing this across link flags.

Edit: I'm using CMake version 3.23.0.

Comment: For linker flags you should use `target_link_options`. Probably what happens here is that cmake detects your use of `-lfoo` ect. as linking a library `foo`, adding it to the list of linked libs and later generates an additional `-lfoo` based on this info while keeping your linker flags...

Comment: @fabian as I mentioned in question, I am getting the link line directly from a pkg-config file provided by a third party dependency. Also, the linker flags in question are positional (e.g. `-Bdynamic` applies to the libraries that follow it), so I'm not sure how I would separate the flags from the libraries.